# Rounded progress within rounded progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to create a custom progress bar in an app we're working on, and the last piece I need is the progress indicator itself. Instead, I want to have that bar be rounded just like the left- and right-hand edges of the progress bar itself, like in the second image (minus the red circle of course).

[image]

[image]

Here's the layout definition of the progress bar (the rest of the layout file omitted for brevity):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_states"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:layout_below="@id/textview2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textview2"
    />
```

and here's the progress_bar_states.xml file:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#20ffff00"/>
            <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#20ffffff"/>
                <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

How do I do this?  I don't see any options to allow me to define the progress indicator at all.  Should I be doing this a different way?  I'm still pretty new at Android, so any guidance is appreciated.

@Ando - your solution is **very** close to what I need.  The start of the indicator movement is the issue now, and I'm guessing it's because it's not a clip like the original.  When the indicator starts, and up to a certain point in the beginning, it looks like it is "squeezed"

[image]

until it gets to the appropriate point then it looks fine:

[image]

How do we accomplish the 'clipping' at the start with this solution?

For @bladefury - as you can see, compared to the leading edge of the image above, it does appear to be flattened.

[image]

EDIT : After not looking at this for quite some time, I looked at a new component at https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar/issues, and it has the same issue as the suggestions here.

Comment: I dont understand your concern. android:progress=".." should work just fine. You can also set it to 'indeterminate'

Comment: I'm not referring to incrementing the progress - I'm talking about the presentation of the progress.  Instead of the progress being a vertical 'bar' like you usually see in a progress bar, I want it to be a rounded indicator to match what the outer boundaries of the bar itself look like.  I will try and update the question with an image of what I want it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library for rounded corner progress bar

```
<com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.RoundCornerProgressBar
        android:layout_width="dimension"
        android:layout_height="dimension"
        app:rcProgress="float"
        app:rcSecondaryProgress="float"
        app:rcMax="float"
        app:rcRadius="dimension"
        app:rcBackgroundPadding="dimension"
        app:rcReverse="boolean"
        app:rcProgressColor="color"
        app:rcSecondaryProgressColor="color"
        app:rcBackgroundColor="color" />
```

Gradle

```
compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
```

https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar

Answer (score 33):

just Change your progress_bar_states.xml file: like below example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#20ffff00" />

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">

    <!-- <clip> -->
    <!-- <shape> -->
    <!-- <solid android:color="@android:color/black" /> -->


    <!-- <corners -->
    <!-- android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" -->
    <!-- android:radius="60dp" -->
    <!-- android:topRightRadius="30dp" /> -->
    <!-- </shape> -->
    <!-- </clip> -->

    <scale
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_progress_primary"
        android:scaleWidth="98%" /><!-- change here -->
</item>
```

here custom_progress_primary.xml file: like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<corners
    android:radius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</shape>
```

Comment: This is **very** close, but there's a small issue at the start of the indicator movement.  I posted a couple of images in the original question to show it.

Comment: @TheIcemanCometh might be try to use clip and i try to provide best one

Comment: check my updated answer and pls change size of progress bar i have tested with 20dp as height and radius 20dp every where  @TheIcemanCometh

Comment: @AndoMasahashi change scaleWidth to 96% and then it worked perfectly fine for me even at progress value 1. Can you explain what scaleWidth is doing here?

Comment: @AndoMasahashi how to set movable loading gradient?

Comment: @AndoMasahashi the scaleWidth to 98% is a perfect answer, thought i don't know why, but it like magic just clip the edge.

Comment: This solution worked for me using firstly this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/50098416/10287345

Answer (score 9):

An option that's perhaps a bit more practical is implementing a custom Progress Bar view.

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends View
{
    // % value of the progressbar.
    int progressBarValue = 0;

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        progressBarValue = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "progressBarValue", 0);
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        progressBarValue = value;
        invalidate();
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float cornerRadius = 30.0f;

        // Draw the background of the bar.
        Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        RectF backgroundRect = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        canvas.drawRoundRect(backgroundRect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, backgroundPaint);

        // Draw the progress bar.
        Paint barPaint = new Paint();
        barPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        barPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        barPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float progress = (backgroundRect.width() / 100) * progressBarValue;
        RectF barRect = new RectF(0, 0, progress, canvas.getClipBounds().bottom);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(barRect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, barPaint);

        // Draw progress text in the middle.
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setTextSize(34);

        String text = progressBarValue + "%";
        Rect textBounds = new Rect();

        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);

        canvas.drawText(text,
                backgroundRect.centerX() - (textBounds.width() / 2),
                backgroundRect.centerY() + (textBounds.height() / 2),
                textPaint);

    }
}
```

Then in your layout:

```
<view.CustomProgressBar
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    progressBarValue="66"/>
```

Which yields the result:

[image: Custom progress bar result]

Comment: How to set max Progress Value?

Comment: It does not work well if you set progressBarValue to a low value (1 for exmple): the green bar gets out of its grey background.

Answer (score 0):

`ProgressBar` uses `ClipDrawable`, which clips drawable with a rectangle. So, you can set a drawable which clips round corner rectangle to progress bar, and here's how:

first, remove `<clip>` tag in your progress bar drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#20ffff00"/>
        <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#20ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
        </shape>
</item>
```

then, extend progress bar like this:

```
public class RoundIndicatorProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

    private static final float CORNER_RADIUS_DP = 60.0f;

    public RoundIndicatorProgressBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public RoundIndicatorProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundIndicatorProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    public void setProgressDrawable(Drawable d) {
        super.setProgressDrawable(tileify(d, false));
    }

    private Drawable tileify(Drawable drawable, boolean clip) {
        if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
            LayerDrawable background = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
            final int N = background.getNumberOfLayers();
            Drawable[] outDrawables = new Drawable[N];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                int id = background.getId(i);
                outDrawables[i] = tileify(background.getDrawable(i),
                        (id == android.R.id.progress || id == android.R.id.secondaryProgress));
            }

            LayerDrawable newBg = new LayerDrawable(outDrawables);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                newBg.setId(i, background.getId(i));
            }

            return newBg;

        } else {
            if (clip) {
                return new RoundClipDrawable(drawable, dp2px(getContext(), CORNER_RADIUS_DP));
            }
        }
        return drawable;
    }
    public static float dp2px(Context context, float dp) {
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return dp * scale;
    }

}
```

and here is `RoundClipDrawable`, modified from `ClipDrawable`:

[RoundClipDrawable.java Gist](https://gist.github.com/bladeFury/d679503ca4c94fa8d2a8)

Comment: See my comment addition in the original question.  The leading edge of the indicator from your solution seems to be flattened ...

Comment: @TheIcemanCometh of course it's flattened because the CORNER_RADIUS in RoundIndicatorProgressBar is 50.0f, for demonstration purpose. In your case, you should set it to a appropriate value.

Comment: You're basing your comment on the assumption that I've kept the same values you have above, which I've already changed to match my requirements (they are 60dp everywhere).  :-)

Comment: Much, much closer.  Now it's at about the same point that @Ando's solution is, except yours does the clipping.  But both solutions have the same issue now - the start of the progress indication.  When the progress starts at zero, and up until it gets to about 20%, it's still flattened at the leading edge of the indicator.  It needs to be fully rounded at the start - from 0% to 100%.  Here's a screencast of the sample app I'm using to test:  http://screencast.com/t/ifdJEJMy2.  I also have the sample app on GitHub, at https://github.com/TheIcemanCometh/RoundedProgressSample1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use seekbar for this too

check my post here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41206481/6033946

Try this , you may be able to do what you want by modifying the color and width and height of the thumb and the seekbar in xml.

Answer (score -1):

> How do we accomplish the 'clipping' at the start with this solution?

What you need is to limit the min progress value, like:

```
final int minProgress = pb.getMax() * {20dp} / pb.getWidth();
progress = Math.max(minProgress, progress);
pb.setProgress(progress);
```

Use code above to postprocess your progress value is ok. It is not a drawable bug, but a right stretch effect.