# Android - How to change default SeekBar thickness?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have this SeekBar:

```
        <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:maxHeight="3dp"/>
```

I have tried to change this SeekBar thickness using maxHeight. But nothing changed. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to change this SeekBar's thickness to 3dp and make look like this:
[image]

So my question is it possible to change SeekBar thickness somehow? If yes, how?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, come up with any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You have to change `progressDrawable` and `thumb` of `SeekBar` to adjust it's thickness :

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/indSeekBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb"
    />
```

Add in drawable folder **seek_bar.xml** :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/seek_bar_background"
                android:width="@dimen/seek_bar_thickness"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:color="@color/seek_bar_secondary_progress"
                    android:width="@dimen/seek_bar_thickness"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape
                android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:color="@color/seek_bar_progress"
                    android:width="@dimen/seek_bar_thickness"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**seek_thumb.xml** :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:height="@dimen/seek_bar_thumb_size"
        android:width="@dimen/seek_bar_thumb_size"
        />
    <solid android:color="@color/seek_bar_progress"/>
</shape>
```

Add to dimension resources (change this to adjust thickness) :

```
<dimen name="seek_bar_thickness">4dp</dimen>
<dimen name="seek_bar_thumb_size">20dp</dimen>
```

Add color resources :

```
<color name="seek_bar_background">#ababab</color>
<color name="seek_bar_progress">#ffb600</color>
<color name="seek_bar_secondary_progress">#3399CC</color>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how to "add to dimension resources"? I see "drawable", "layout", and "values" in my `res` folder in Android Studio, but no "dimension"

Comment: @stevendesu create file dimens.xml in values resource folder, technically you can declare any string, color, dimension resources in any XML file in values folder enclosed  in <resources> </resources> tag

Answer (score 14):

You should do like this:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_style"
    />
```

The thumb is the circle which can be dragged, and the progressDrasable is the style of progress.

**seek_style.xml**:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff0099CC"
                    android:centerColor="#ff3399CC"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff6699CC"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**seek.xml**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        />
    <solid android:color="#60f0"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [**`Slider`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md) provided by the Material Components Library.

Use the **`app:trackHeight="xxdp"`** (the default value is `4dp`) to change the height of the track bar.

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        app:trackHeight="12dp"
        .../>
```

[image]

If you want to change also the thumb radius you can use the **`app:thumbRadius`** attribute:

```
        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            app:trackHeight="12dp"
            app:thumbRadius="16dp"
            ../>
```

[image]

It requires the version **1.2.0** of the library.

Comment: Slider doesn't seem to have support for things like secondary progress.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with:
android:scaleX="2"

Answer (score 1):

Just set **scaleY** for seekbar height, and padding to remove outside padding.

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="0sp"
        android:paddingTop="0sp"
        android:scaleY="3" />
```

Answer (score -5):

You can change the thickness of your seekbar using the attributes `minHeight` and `maxHeight`

`android:minHeight="5dp"`

`android:maxHeight="5dp"`

Here's how I'd do it in your xml:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:minHeight="5dp"
    android:maxHeight="5dp"/>
```

Comment: This actually works, may I ask downvoters for the explanation why this is wrong?

Comment: This is a hammer fix. It will not work sometimes and it will lead you to visual bugs.