# Android - Custom SeekBar - round corners on progress bar

Tags: android, rounding, android-seekbar

Trying to make a custom SeekBar. I want to achieve this.

[image]

What I have done so far is this. I can't find a way to round the corners on the progress bar.

[image]

Can someone help with this? Here is my code

main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"  
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:progress="90"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumbler_small"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" 
        android:indeterminate="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

styled_progress.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape> 
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#d2e5ff"
                android:endColor="#d2e5ff"
                android:angle="45"
        />
        <corners 
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
                android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
                android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#808080"
                    android:endColor="#808080"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
            <corners 
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
                android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
                android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#c5e6eb"
                android:endColor="#61cabb"
                android:angle="45" />
             <corners 
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
                android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
                android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
        </shape>

    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded progress within rounded progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130359/rounded-progress-within-rounded-progress-bar)

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский Progress bar is not the same as seek bar

Answer (score 5):

[you can see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHfmH.jpg)

This sulotion was the only way i could do this.
Hope this help

this is my seekbar :

```
         <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/simpleProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:background="@null"
            android:shape="oval"
            android:splitTrack="false"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_background"
            android:secondaryProgress="0"
            android:thumbOffset="10dp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/oval_seekbar_thumb" />
```

this is (progress_background.xml) :

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@color/grey_line"
            android:startColor="@color/grey_line" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/blue"
                android:startColor="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="90dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

and this is the thumb (oval_seekbar_thumb.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:width="3dp"/>
            <size android:height="12dp" android:width="12dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The height of the thumb should be same as the height of the seekbar to look properly.