# Shape padding not working pre 6 Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar, android-shape

Seems like shape padding doesn't work on pre 6 Android. I'm trying to add padding to custom `ProgressBar` background gradient and that what I have:

Android 6.0:

[image]

Android 5.0 and below:

[image]

`pb_shape.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <corners android:radius="12dip" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dip"
            android:color="@color/primary_white" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="@color/primary_black"
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="@color/primary_black"
            android:gradientRadius="12dip"
            android:startColor="@color/primary_black" />

        <!--This not working pre 6 android-->
        <padding
            android:bottom="4dp"
            android:left="4dp"
            android:right="4dp"
            android:top="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>


<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dip" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:endColor="@color/primary_teal"
                android:startColor="@color/primary_blue_dark" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

I've already tried to wrap those both items in distinct xml files and set padding there like that but it takes no effect:

```
 <item
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pb_gradient_bg"
    />
```

Any ideas what causes this behavior and what could be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found a way round for this. It was needed to create transparent stroke for gradient with needed width and it does exactly what was needed.

For solution check my answer in [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160011/4673764)

Happy coding :)